# AJAX: Validator ranges are not updated

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces

On a JSF view I have a [`<p:progressBar />`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf), which shows the actual view if the initialization went correctly. Here's a simplified version of the implementation: `bean` is a `@ViewScoped` managed bean, it's `init()` method sets the validator range (`max`). As you can see, if `<p:progressBar />` is finished, it updates `main-container` and then hides itself and shows `main-container`:

```
<h:form id="loadingForm" prependId="false">

    <p:progressBar id="prog" widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" interval="400"
        value="#{progress.progressValue}" >
        <p:ajax event="complete"
            oncomplete="$('#prog').hide(); $('#main-container').show()"
            update=":main-container" />
    </p:progressBar>

    <p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" onstart="pbAjax.start();"
        action="#{bean.init}" />
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="main-container" style="display: none;">

    <h:form id="formWithInputs" prependId="false">
        <p:growl id="messages" />

        <p:inputText id="maxA" value="#{bean.val}">
            <f:validateDoubleRange maximum="#{bean.max}" />
        </p:inputText>

        <p:commandButton id="submitBtn" update="messages" />
    </h:form>

</h:panelGroup>
```

After `main-container` is shown, the components are updated and rendered correctly. However, when I submit `formWithInputs`, I get a validation error despite being able to print the correct value for `max` in the backing bean:

> maxA: Validation Error: Value is greater than allowable maximum of "0"

What do I have to change to make the validator use the updated value from the backing bean?

I'm using MyFaces 2.1.14, PrimeFaces 4.0, GlassFish 3.1.2.2.

**UPDATE – SSCCE:**

[Download Eclipse Project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14670704/Bug.zip)

Tested on [MyFaces 2.1.14](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/myfaces/binaries/myfaces-core-assembly-2.1.14-bin.zip), [PrimeFaces 4.0](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/primefaces/primefaces/4.0/primefaces-4.0.jar), GlassFish 3.1.2.2 with Chrome 32 / Firefox 26.

*XHTML*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="loadingForm" prependId="false">
        <p:progressBar id="prog" widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" interval="400"
            value="#{viewMBean.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%">
            <p:ajax event="complete"
              oncomplete="$(pbAjax.jqId).hide(); $('#main-container').show();"
              update=":main-container" />
        </p:progressBar>

        <p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" onstart="pbAjax.start();"
            action="#{viewMBean.init}" />
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="main-container" style="display: none;">
        <h:form id="inputForm" prependId="false">
            <p:messages id="messages" />

            <p:inputText id="maxI" value="#{viewMBean.val}">
                <f:validateDoubleRange maximum="#{viewMBean.max}" />
            </p:inputText>

            <p:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="SUBMIT" update="messages"
                action="#{viewMBean.submit}" />

        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:body>
</html>
```

*ViewMBean.java*:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ViewMBean implements Serializable {

    private Integer max;
    private Integer val;

    private Integer progress;

    public ViewMBean() {
        this.max = 0;
        this.val = 30;

        this.progress = 0;
    }

    public Integer getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(Integer max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public Integer getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(Integer progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public void init() throws InterruptedException {

        //simulates processing
        setProgress(20);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        setProgress(75);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //define maximum value
        this.max = 100;

        setProgress(100);
    }

    public void submit() {
        Logger.getLogger(ViewMBean.class.toString())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, "Max: " + this.max + ", Val: " + this.val);
    }

}
```

*web.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Test</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production<!-- Development --></param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
        <param-value>65536</param-value> <!-- 64KB. -->
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value> <!-- Should be -1 for production. -->
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- MyFaces settings -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>100</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Servlets and filters. -->

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>bug.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

*OUTPUT*: (After clicking SUBMIT)

> maxI: Validation Error: Value is greater than allowable maximum of "0"

Note that this works if I change my bean to `@SessionScoped`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to figure out the exact cause, however gave [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) a try. I switched `<f:validateDoubleRange />` tags to [`<o:validator />`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/validator) tags.

```
<o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.DoubleRange"
             maximum="#{viewMBean.max}" />
```

Works like a charm.

Another workaround that works is to use the validators via their `binding` attribute, and initialize them from the backing bean directly. See [DoubleRangeValidator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/DoubleRangeValidator.html).

**Tag:**

```
<f:validateDoubleRange binding="#{viewMBean.validator}" />
```

**Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewMBean implements Serializable {

    private DoubleRangeValidator validator;

    public ViewMBean {
        this.validator = new DoubleRangeValidator(20.0);
    }

    public void submit() {
        Double max = 30.0;
        this.validator.setMaximum(max);

        Logger.getLogger(ViewMBean.class.toString())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, "Max: " + max);
    }

}
```

Comment: I was able to replicate the problem. It actually only occurred to me when I switched from mojarra to myfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Could not replicate the error. If there is a problem, I believe it would be somewhere in your `@ManagedBean`.

Here is the code I've done to simulate your problem:

```
<h:form id="loadingForm" prependId="false">
    <p:progressBar id="prog" widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" interval="400"
                   value="#{viewMBean.progress}" >
        <p:ajax event="complete"
            oncomplete="console.log('a'); $(pbAjax.jqId).hide(); $('#main-container').show()"
            update=":main-container" />
    </p:progressBar>
    <p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" onstart="pbAjax.start();"
                     action="#{viewMBean.init}" />
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="main-container" style="display: none;">
    <h:form id="formWithInputs" prependId="false">
        <p:messages id="messages" />
        <p:inputText id="maxA" value="#{viewMBean.val}">
            <f:validateDoubleRange maximum="#{viewMBean.max}" />
        </p:inputText>
        <p:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Validate" />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The `@ManagedBean`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewMBean implements Serializable {

    private Integer progress = 0;

    private Integer max = 0;

    private Integer val = 0;

    public Integer getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(Integer progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public Integer getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(Integer max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public void init() throws InterruptedException {
        //simulates processing
        progress = 50;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        progress = 75;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        progress = 100;
        //define maximum value
        max = 100;
    }

}
```

Comment: What was the outcome for you? I guess nothing happens when you submit. The code in my question was kind of pseudo-ish, sorry about that. Try to change `<p:messages />` to `<p:growl />`, and update it with the `<p:commandButton />`. I've changed the code in the question accordingly.

Comment: It worked as expected. When the progress bar finishes, the input appears and the maxvalue is updated from 0 to 100. When I enter 101 I get the validation error. Any number below submits just fine.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the exact sources from my project.